is there a way to drop in my netrw location info into my jumplist
I'm aware that from a file I can type :Rex to go back to my location in Netrw Directory Listing. My muscle memory is deep here, is there a way to drop in my Newrw Directory location into my jump list?
Ideally every time I open a file from the Netrw Directory Listing it drops a line in the jump list so that hitting <c-o> automatically takes me back
Is there a way to do this, maybe a small vimscript? I'm on production and want to avoid pluggins.

Isn't that the default behavior?

Im on a Google VM instance with Bookworm and it is not.

Create a file in the location ~/vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim with the contents:
augroup NetrwJumplist
  autocmd! * <buffer>
  autocmd BufLeave <buffer> normal! m'
augroup END

This will set up an autocommand to add a location to the jumplist with the m' command just before leaving a netrw explorer.
If you'd rather keep the code in your .vimrc, you could try the following (but note that this is untested, because I prefer the ftplugin solution):
augroup NetrwJumplist
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType netrw autocmd BufLeave <buffer> normal! m'
augroup END


WORKS! Thanks you so much. So cool.

I believe the first snippet’s autocmd! is incorrect and should be autocmd! * <buffer>; https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/386bbdd7d70f409707fbe28a3a99ec18f89a5f86/links/vim/after/ftplugin/clojure.vim#L23

@D.BenKnoble Somehow that’s never occurred to me before. I’ve been doing buffer-local autocommands wrong this entire time! ‍♂️

:))) It's definitely a little weird.
